# Prototype Pattern in Java - the clone() method

Tags: java, design-patterns, clone, cloneable, prototype-pattern

So, I've been reading on Design Patterns and the Prototype Patterns confuses me. I believe one of the points of using it is avoiding the need for using the **new** operator. Then I look at this example:

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype/java/1

First, Their idea of Prototype implements a clone() method, which is weird. Wikipedia also says I need a pure virtual method clone to be implemented by subclasses (why?). Doesn't Java already provide such a method, doing exactly what we need it to do (which is to create a copy of an object instead of instancing it from scratch)? Second, the clone method invokes the operator **new**! Surely the example is wrong? (In that case I should be studying Design Patterns elsewhere, heh?). Can someone tell if this correction makes it right?:

```
static class Tom implements Cloneable implements Xyz {
    public Xyz    cloan()    {
      return Tom.clone(); //instead of new I use clone() from Interface Cloneable
    }
    public String toString() {
      return "ttt";
    }
  }
```

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: "I use clone() from Interface Cloneable" There is no `clone()` in the interface `Cloneable`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of prototype pattern is having a blueprint / template from which you can spawn your instance. It's not merely to "avoid using new in Java"

If you implement prototype pattern in Java, then yes by all means override the existing `clone()` method from Object class, no need to create a new one. (Also need implement Clonable interface or you'll get exception)

As an example:

```
// Student class implements Clonable
Student rookieStudentPrototype = new Student();
rookieStudentPrototype.setStatus("Rookie");
rookieStudentPrototype.setYear(1);

// By using prototype pattern here we don't need to re-set status and
// year, only the name. Status and year already copied by clone
Student tom = rookieStudentPrototype.clone();
tom.setName("Tom");

Student sarah = rookieStudentPrototype.clone();
sarah.setName("Sarah");
```

Comment: "leverage the existing clone() method from Cloneable interface" There is no `clone()` method in the `Cloneable` interface

Comment: If you run around using a clone method everywhere you're likely to run into some nasty problems. In real life you have to decide if you want to do a deep clone or a shallow one. What about cloning List implementations or two-dimensional arrays? The above is a really simple example. Often a better approach is a copy constructor that handles those cases efficiently. [In _Effective Java_, Josh Bloch says the Cloneable interface is severely broken.](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Answer (score 4):

A design pattern is simply a way of representing how software is written in a reproducible way. There are in fact different syntactical approaches to achieving the same thing.

So, the Prototype pattern is simply an approach that uses a master copy to implement some overriding functionality. There are several ways to do this in Java (as well, I believe in other languages). Here is one that uses the 'new' keyword, and it's based on using an interface as a contract with implementing concrete classes. Then a single method takes a concrete implementation of the interface and performs the same operation:

```
// software contract
interface Shape { 
   public void draw();
} 
// concrete implementations
class Line implements Shape {
   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("line");
   }
}
class Square implements Shape {
   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("square");
   }
}
...
class Painting {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Shape s1 = new Line ();
      Shape s2 = new Square ();
      ...
      paint (s1);
      paint (s2);
      ...
   }
   // single method executes against the software contract as a prototype
   static void paint (Shape s) {
      s.draw ();
   }
}
```

You can read more at http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/prototype.html or check out the [main Design Pattern site](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/). The information is presented there complete with references.

Comment: At first glance this implementation is more like what I was expecting. Thanks for pointing it out. I know specifics of implementing Patterns may vary, but I still feel there's something wrong with the one I linked (and Wikipedia, possibly?).

Answer (score 3):

The example you've linked is correct and your code

```
return Tom.clone();
```

won't compile because `clone()` is not a static method.

Cloning is not about avoiding the use of `new` operator but creating a new instance that has the same state (values of its member fields) as that of the object that's being cloned. Hence, `clone()` is not static but an instance method so that you can create a new instance (and using *new* isn't a problem) that mirrors the state of the object that `clone()` has been invoked upon.

It's just that your example classes (like Tom) are so simple (with no state) that all that the `clone()` method is doing is to instantiate a *new* instance. If it had a bit more complex state (say an `ArrayList` of objects) the `clone()` method would have to do a deep copy of the `ArrayList` as well.

To elaborate with one of your example classes, assume that `Tom` had some *instance state*. Now, the `clone()` would also have to make sure that the copy being returned matches the state of the current one.

```
static class Tom implements Xyz {

    private String name;

    public Tom() {
      this.name = "Tom"; // some state
    }

    public Xyz clone()    {
      Tom t = new Tom();
      t.setName(getName()); // copy current state
      return t;
    }

   public String toString() {
      return getName();
    }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, if the class had an ArrayList (or any other attributes), my clone (or cloan(), in my case) method would create a "new Tom()" and then proceed to copy attribute values stored from the prototype onto the new object? If so, I get it, and the problem was really the example doesn't highlight the usefulness of the Prototype that well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I've added an example as well to highlight this.

Comment: Clone method when call the super.clone() method it will return the same instance unless the method is overrided and you make a manual deep copy or use any existing library for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  BeanUtils.copyProperties method to do the same which is provided by  Spring framework org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

Answer (score 0):

Prototype actually **"Doesn't"** save calls to `new` operator. It simply facilitates that a shallow copy of non-sensitive attributes are made by calling the so called `clone`. For example,

1) You have `UserAccount` which has a primary user and linked user details

2) `UserAccount` also has it's PK called `userAccountId`.

When you put all your `UserAccount` objects in a collection, of course, you would like the `userAccountId` to be different. But you still  have to call `new UserAccount` for each links you have. Otherwise, you will end up modifying one object 100 times expecting 100 things in return. Also, if you have this `UserAccount` as a composition (not aggregation) depending on the attribute's sensitivity, you may have to call `new` on them too.

e.g if `UserAccount` has `Person` object (and if 'Person' has it's own compositions), you have to call `new` to ensure that their references are appropriately set.