# Is Prototype Design Pattern just an implementation of Clonable?

Tags: java, design-patterns, prototype

I'm not really a Pattern user and I'm trying to change that. I'm reading about this Design Pattern and from what I understand the whole idea is that I should implement Clonable and use clone() method to make a new object based on existing one. Is that what this Pattern is about or is it more to it ?

Comment: I think it is the reverse. Java implements prototype using Cloneable

Comment: Good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203493/prototype-pattern-in-java-the-clone-method